# Is there a way to export static blocks and cms pages in mass from local to online?

Tags: magento-1.9, static-block, cms-pages, static-content, page-content

I have a localhost version of Magento and another which is already in Hostgator. My changes on files I can ftp quick and easily, of course. But I would like to know if there is some faster way to "upload" my static blocks and cms pages I've created in localhost instead of having to create all them again, manually (it would be a very painful task, for sure), maybe through phpmyadmin or through an awesome "free-preferred" extension.

Thank u

Comment: https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/import-export-cms-pages-blocks.html
I found one extension as well you can use it.

Comment: If you want to get only those block that you have created for change then just open CMS block and cms page table then select those rows to be imported, then there will be options given below to Export, click on it. And you can use this file to import data to live server. If you had selected different stores for CMS block or page then just crate a new SQL file for CMS block/ store and fill new block IDs and store IDs that you want to and run it in query Windows. Or you can use above given magento extension by @Magento2 Learner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that you can export database table of CMS block and CMS page from phpmyadmin and import that in server phpmyadmin , make sure when export, export only data not structure and data.

4 tables:

- cms_block
- cms_block_store
- cms_page
- cms_page_store

First take backup.

Answer (score 1):

In Magento 1.9, all static blocks and CMS pages are located in 4 tables: cms_block_store, cms_block, cms_page_store, cms_page.

Open phpmyadmin in localhost and export them. After that, you can import to phpmyadmin in Hostgator (don't forget to backup).

Hope it helps

Comment: In addition, is there some extension maybe that is able to perform that "magic", like exporting cms pages, static blocks, maybe some config etc?

Answer (score 1):

In Magento 1.9, all static blocks and CMS pages are located into following 4 tables in database:

1. cms_block_store
2. cms_block
3. cms_page_store
4. cms_page

Do to your Database and export them. After that, you need to import these tables into your new database. Don't forget to backup.

Comment: Great man, it worked! The only thing is that I had to disable the foreign key checking to 0 and, after importing data, to 1, because I was getting an error.